# Are there ways for me to generate $40k per year in perpetuity from $300k?

Tags: investing, interest, rate-of-return

Why or why not?

Even if I did get $40k once, how unlikely is it to happen again?

Some obvious answer are getting a job paying $40k a year (reasonable, but not what I'm asking) and spending the principal (which doesn't answer the "in perpetuity" part). Please, I'm looking for answer explaining why a certain portfolio could *theoretically* earn that kind of money, or arguments as to why a portfolio like that doesn't exist (or can't reliably exist year after year).

Comment: 13.3% a year in perpetuity?  LOL.  Not gonna happen.

Comment: Step 1:  Get a job making at least 40K per year.

Comment: I really don't think this question is opinion-based at all.  One can factually state whether or not such investments exist. (Of course, "No.")   It should have just been flagged "low quality" or such, IMO

Comment: Nothing that is passive investing.  If you're willing to do some work, you could try loan sharking.  I understand that the competition can be rather fierce, though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the least risky way for me to generate $40k per year in perpetuity from $300k?

## On the markets...

If you mean strictly using the markets (so, some sort of system involving stocks, bonds, commodities, and derivatives thereof), the literal answer and the only answer is, by "day trading".  I.E., by actively trading.

The fact is, of folks who "trade actively" (whether literally "day" trading, or trading on other short timescales), a very very few do make a living at it.

At a wild guess, of every 10,000 folks who try active trading.  9,000 are "civilians" who put 10 to 100 thousand in and obviously just instantly lose it all.

Of the other 1000 who try their hand, at a wild guess I'd say 10 make it and can and do generate a living consistently.

{Note though that it costs 100s of thousands in losses to learn the trade; we'll set that aside since this is all theoretical.}

Thus in some sense your "best chance" (indeed, only chance) to make the money you're talking about on the markets, is to become a (successful) active trader (a "day trader"),

at a wild guess your chances of success are about 5 to 10 in ten thousand.

{Do note though that "day trading" is incredibly hard work and incredibly time consuming. No matter how much $ I made, after a few years I moved along to something else since it is far easier, and you work far less hours per week, to make money with a business or just a successful job.}

[Note, regarding just ordinary "investments", a fund or the like, it's obviously completely inconceivable to get that sort of return.  At first I **assumed it was a typo**, OP is hoping to make *four* thousand a year, not forty.  (You'd be somewhat lucky to make the *four* thousand, really!)]

## Nothing to do with the markets ...

The **only way** in practice you can make 10s of thousands a year, say 40 or 50 thousand a year, with 300k to begin with, is some sort of business.

I've never owned a **franchize** but they seem to work for some. At a wild guess I'd say half of them are a scam, or are just hopeless, and half work out great.

Starting your own business from scratch (non-franchize) can definitely work, but surely only 1 in 10 or so end up making money.

(It is almost always better to buy an existing business, than start from scratch. So, buy an existing coffee shop, perhaps that's doing badly and build it up, rather than starting a coffee shop from scratch.)

Note though that "Your Business" is an 80 hour a week proposition.

If you can find a situation where you are a **true silent partner** - so, someone you know needs a 300k investment to make the next Facebook-For-Dogs or a new type of mousetrap or whatever - that could possibly work. But in the vast majority of cases (say, 95% ??) you'll just lose all your money straightaway.

## Be the landlord?

It's *possible* you could do something like purchase a $600k block of flats with $300k down and it would actually be cashflow positive to the tune of your $40,000 a year.

I know little/nothing about rentals, so maybe someone who does could comment on this in general, if it is realistic.

Answer (score 2):

The inflation-adjusted rate of return on stocks, for the kind of large-cap stocks included in the S&P 500, has historically run about 7%, which gives you about $20k per year, or half of what you're hoping for. (I assume you were talking about $40k before taxes.) Having your assets 100% invested in stocks is already very risky, so if you need this money to live on, and can't risk losing the whole thing, then the answer to your question is really that you can't do that.

If you're willing to accept a pretty high risk of losing the whole amount of money, then you can accept higher risk in return for higher returns. You can theoretically try to do this by leveraging your investment, i.e., by borrowing additional money to invest. The reality is that if it were this easy to do, everybody would be doing it. You could conceivably do it, for instance, if you owned something valuable to use as collateral. But the outcome might very well be that you would then lose everything, including the collateral.

Comment: If there were any investment that reasonable people could all agree provided a greater return for its risk than other investments, that would be an agreement that that investment was underpriced. But any reasonable person who thinks an asset was underpriced wouldn't sell it. So that would mean nobody could buy it unless there were a lot of unreasonable people who happen to hold the exceptional asset. That doesn't seem like something that would happen.

Comment: "If you're willing to accept a pretty high risk of losing the whole amount of money, then you can accept higher risk in return for higher returns."  Actually I don't think that's correct.  There's no ultra-ultra-ultra high risk highly leveraged Thing out there that returns the fantasy percentages at hand here.  (If anyone knows one, do tell!)

Comment: @Fattie: The truth or falsehood of your claim depends on a bunch of things, including the mathematical definitions we choose for "return" and "risk." If "return" is defined as an expectation value, then there is no fundamental principle that even says the expectation value of the return on an investment has to be finite. It's perfectly possible logically that some investments  have returns described by something like a Cauchy distribution, which doesn't have a well-defined expectation value.

Comment: @BenCrowell , you may misunderstand me. There are literally *no products available* in that risk/reward range.  (I mean, obviously, one can personally trade, options or whatever, and jack up your guessed risk to whatever level you wish.)  But there are no funds, etc, today which aim for 13%.  (When I said that "wasn't correct" I purely meant the OP, as asked, has no such funds or other products available. - everything you said is of course totally correct Ben!! )